# Resumable HTTP download class - Follow-up

Tags: c#, http, network-file-transfer

Is there a better way to calculate the download speed than what I'm currently doing now? Are there any suggestions on improving the updated code?

Pure version:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace Downloader
{
    public interface ILogger
    {
        void LogMessage(string message, params Object[] args);
    }

    public class ConsoleLogger : ILogger
    {
        public void LogMessage(string message, params Object[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(message, args));
        }
    }

    public class Download
    {
        private ILogger _Logger;

        public CallingClass(ILogger logger)
        {
            _Logger = logger;
        }

        public event EventHandler<DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs> ResumablityChanged;
        public event EventHandler<DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> ProgressChanged;
        public event EventHandler Completed;

        public bool stop = true; // by default stop is true
        public bool paused = false;
        SemaphoreSlim pauseLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

        string filename;

        public void DownloadFile(string DownloadLink, string Path)
        {
            filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Path);

            stop = false; // always set this bool to false, everytime this method is called

            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path);
            long existingLength = 0;
            if (fileInfo.Exists)
                existingLength = fileInfo.Length;

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(DownloadLink);
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.AddRange(existingLength);

            try
            {
                using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    long fileSize = existingLength + response.ContentLength; //response.ContentLength gives me the size that is remaining to be downloaded
                    bool downloadResumable; // need it for not sending any progress

                    if ((int)response.StatusCode == 206) //same as: response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.PartialContent
                    {
                        logger.LogMessage("Resumable");
                        downloadResumable = true;
                    }
                    else // sometimes a server that supports partial content will lose its ability to send partial content(weird behavior) and thus the download will lose its resumability
                    {
                        logger.LogMessage("Not Resumable");
                        existingLength = 0;
                        downloadResumable = false;
                    }
                    OnResumabilityChanged(new DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs(downloadResumable));

                    using (var saveFileStream = fileInfo.Open(downloadResumable ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        byte[] downBuffer = new byte[4096];
                        int byteSize = 0;
                        long totalReceived = byteSize + existingLength;
                        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                        while (!stop && (byteSize = stream.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            saveFileStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, byteSize);
                            totalReceived += byteSize;

                            float currentSpeed = totalReceived / (float)sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                            OnProgressChanged(new DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs(totalReceived, fileSize, (long)currentSpeed));

                            pauseLock.Wait();
                            pauseLock.Release();
                        }
                        sw.Stop();
                    }
                }
                if (!stop) OnCompleted(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                logger.LogMessage(e);
            }
        }

        public void pause()
        {
            if (!paused)
            {
                paused = true;
                // Note this cannot block for more than a moment
                // since the download thread doesn't keep the lock held
                pauseLock.Wait();
            }
        }

        public void unpause()
        {
            if (paused)
            {
                paused = false;
                pauseLock.Release();
            }
        }

        public void StopDownload()
        {
            stop = true;
            this.unpause();  // stop waiting on lock if needed
        }

        protected virtual void OnResumabilityChanged(DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = ResumablityChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnProgressChanged(DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = ProgressChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnCompleted(EventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = Completed;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

    public class DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs(bool canResume)
        {
            ResumeSupported = canResume;
        }
        public bool ResumeSupported { get; private set; }
    }

    public class DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs(long totalReceived, long fileSize, long currentSpeed)
        {
            BytesReceived = totalReceived;
            TotalBytesToReceive = fileSize;
            CurrentSpeed = currentSpeed;
        }

        public long BytesReceived { get; private set; }
        public long TotalBytesToReceive { get; private set; }
        public float ProgressPercentage 
        { 
            get 
            { 
                return ((float)BytesReceived / (float)TotalBytesToReceive) * 100; 
            } 
        }
        public float CurrentSpeed { get; private set; } // in bytes
        public TimeSpan TimeLeft
        {
            get
            {
                var bytesRemainingtoBeReceived = TotalBytesToReceive - BytesReceived;
                return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(bytesRemainingtoBeReceived / CurrentSpeed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

GUI version:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.IO;
using System.Net;
using System.Threading;

namespace Downloader
{
    public interface ILogger
    {
        void LogMessage(string message, params Object[] args);
    }

    public class ConsoleLogger : ILogger
    {
        public void LogMessage(string message, params Object[] args)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(string.Format(message, args));
        }
    }

    public class Download
    {
        private ILogger _Logger;

        public CallingClass(ILogger logger)
        {
            _Logger = logger;
        }

        public event EventHandler<DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs> ResumablityChanged;
        public event EventHandler<DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs> ProgressChanged;
        public event EventHandler Completed;

        public bool stop = true; // by default stop is true
        public bool paused = false;
        SemaphoreSlim pauseLock = new SemaphoreSlim(1);

        string filename;

        public void DownloadFile(string DownloadLink, string Path)
        {
            filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Path);

            stop = false; // always set this bool to false, everytime this method is called

            var fileInfo = new FileInfo(Path);
            long existingLength = 0;
            if (fileInfo.Exists)
                existingLength = fileInfo.Length;

            var request = (HttpWebRequest)HttpWebRequest.Create(DownloadLink);
            request.Proxy = null;
            request.AddRange(existingLength);

            try
            {
                using (var response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse())
                {
                    long fileSize = existingLength + response.ContentLength; //response.ContentLength gives me the size that is remaining to be downloaded
                    bool downloadResumable; // need it for not sending any progress

                    if ((int)response.StatusCode == 206) //same as: response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.PartialContent
                    {
                        logger.LogMessage("Resumable");
                        downloadResumable = true;
                    }
                    else // sometimes a server that supports partial content will lose its ability to send partial content(weird behavior) and thus the download will lose its resumability
                    {
                        logger.LogMessage("Not Resumable");
                        if (existingLength > 0)
                        {
                            if (ResumeUnsupportedWarning() == false) // warn and ask for confirmation to continue if the half downloaded file is unresumable
                            {
                                return;
                            }
                        }
                        existingLength = 0;
                        downloadResumable = false;
                    }
                    OnResumabilityChanged(new DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs(downloadResumable));

                    using (var saveFileStream = fileInfo.Open(downloadResumable ? FileMode.Append : FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write))
                    using (var stream = response.GetResponseStream())
                    {
                        byte[] downBuffer = new byte[4096];
                        int byteSize = 0;
                        long totalReceived = byteSize + existingLength;
                        var sw = Stopwatch.StartNew();
                        while (!stop && (byteSize = stream.Read(downBuffer, 0, downBuffer.Length)) > 0)
                        {
                            saveFileStream.Write(downBuffer, 0, byteSize);
                            totalReceived += byteSize;

                            float currentSpeed = totalReceived / (float)sw.Elapsed.TotalSeconds;
                            OnProgressChanged(new DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs(totalReceived, fileSize, (long)currentSpeed));

                            pauseLock.Wait();
                            pauseLock.Release();
                        }
                        sw.Stop();
                    }
                }
                if (!stop) OnCompleted(EventArgs.Empty);
            }
            catch (WebException e)
            {
                System.Windows.MessageBox.Show(e.Message, filename);
            }
        }

        public void pause()
        {
            if (!paused)
            {
                paused = true;
                // Note this cannot block for more than a moment
                // since the download thread doesn't keep the lock held
                pauseLock.Wait();
            }
        }

        public void unpause()
        {
            if (paused)
            {
                paused = false;
                pauseLock.Release();
            }
        }

        public void StopDownload()
        {
            stop = true;
            this.unpause();  // stop waiting on lock if needed
        }

        public bool ResumeUnsupportedWarning()
        {
            var messageBoxResult = System.Windows.MessageBox.Show("When trying to resume the download , Mackerel got a response from the server that it doesn't support resuming the download. It's possible that it's a temporary error of the server, and you will be able to resume the file at a later time, but at this time Mackerel can download this file from the beginning.\n\nDo you want to download this file from the beginning?", filename, System.Windows.MessageBoxButton.YesNo);
            if (messageBoxResult == System.Windows.MessageBoxResult.Yes)
            {
                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnResumabilityChanged(DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = ResumablityChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnProgressChanged(DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = ProgressChanged;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }

        protected virtual void OnCompleted(EventArgs e)
        {
            var handler = Completed;
            if (handler != null)
            {
                handler(this, e);
            }
        }
    }

    public class DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs(bool canResume)
        {
            ResumeSupported = canResume;
        }
        public bool ResumeSupported { get; private set; }
    }

    public class DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs : EventArgs
    {
        public DownloadProgressChangedEventArgs(long totalReceived, long fileSize, long currentSpeed)
        {
            BytesReceived = totalReceived;
            TotalBytesToReceive = fileSize;
            CurrentSpeed = currentSpeed;
        }

        public long BytesReceived { get; private set; }
        public long TotalBytesToReceive { get; private set; }
        public float ProgressPercentage 
        { 
            get 
            { 
                return ((float)BytesReceived / (float)TotalBytesToReceive) * 100; 
            } 
        }
        public float CurrentSpeed { get; private set; } // in bytes
        public TimeSpan TimeLeft
        {
            get
            {
                var bytesRemainingtoBeReceived = TotalBytesToReceive - BytesReceived;
                return TimeSpan.FromSeconds(bytesRemainingtoBeReceived / CurrentSpeed);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

The first bit of code that sprang to my eyes had been something which should just be deleted.

> ```
> public bool stop = true; // by default stop is true
> ```

What is this comment for ? It doesn't add any value to your code because it is clearly visible to the reader that the `stop` variable is initialized to `true`.

Such comments are only adding noise to the code and should be deleted.

But this isn't the only problem with it. Making a variable `public` violates encapsulation. Instead of using `public` variables you should use `public` properties. In this way you can control/validate any given value.

---

Based on the [naming guidelines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229002.aspx) methods should be named using `PascalCase` casing, so `pause()` -> `Pause()` and the badly named `unpause()` method should be better named `Resume()`.

Based on the same naming guidelines method parameters should be named using `camelCase` casing.

---

You should either use always braces `{}` or never for single line `if` statements (`for` and `else` the same). Right now you are inconsistently switching your styles. Sometimes you use braces, sometimes you don use them and put the single command on the same line like the `if` and sometimes you place the single command on the next line.

I would like to encourage you to always use them to make your code less error prone.

---

**DownloadFile()**

- > ```
  > filename = System.IO.Path.GetFileName(Path);
  > ```

  this variable isn't used at all, so there is no need to keep it.
- > ```
  > if ((int)response.StatusCode == 206) //same as: response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.PartialContent
  > ```

  instead of using a comment about what is meant, why don't you just use the enum ? It would be more obvious if you write

  ```
  if (response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.PartialContent)
  ```

  no one would need to read the comment because it is clear what you meant.

  But this whole `if..else` statement shouldn't be there. You should add a private method `LogResumable(bool downloadResumable)` where you do the logging based on the method parameter. This reduces the code of the `DownloadFile()` method.

  By ectracting this to the said method the former `if..else` woulc look like so

  ```
  bool downloadResumable = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
  if (!downloadResumable) 
  {
      existingLength = 0;
  }
  LogResumable(downloadResumable);
  OnResumabilityChanged(new DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs(downloadResumable));
  ```

  ---

I don't understand why you have a version of this class which is only for a `GUI`. This isn't the way it should be. You should just use the `pure` version and adjust the `DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs` class to have a property for the `existingLength` property.

By changing the order of the changed `if..else` statements to

```
    bool downloadResumable = response.StatusCode == HttpStatusCode.PartialContent;
    OnResumabilityChanged(new DownloadStatusChangedEventArgs(downloadResumable));
    if (!downloadResumable) 
    {
        existingLength = 0;
    }
    LogResumable(downloadResumable);
```

you could use the `pure` version inside a gui and could use the event to decide if the download should be aborted. Sure this needs some more work, because you need to extend the `Download` class to react on abortation but that is always better than using 2 almost same classes.